# How to build a .deb file for CMake from source?

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, packaging

How do you produce a .deb file for ubuntu from the CMake source code?

I already installed (hopefully most of) the build dependencies using apt:

`sudo apt-get build-dep cmake`

checked out the cmake repo using git:

`git clone http://www.cmake.org/cmake.git`

built cmake using the older cmake I already have:

`cd cmake`
`cmake .`
`make`

what next?  This is surprisingly hard to google for; most people want to know how to package their own stuff ~with cmake. The CMake install instructions just specify a `make install` but dependency hell is bad enough ~with a package manager in my experience.

Comment: If you are going to create Ubuntu PPA then CPack won't work for you because launchpad build server only executes `dpkg-buildpackage` i.e. expects that you have `debian` folder with manifest. See my comment for details https://stackoverflow.com/a/65582856/1049542

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After building cmake, use [cpack](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cpack.1.html) for generate `deb` package:

```
cpack -G DEB
```

It should be run from the build tree.

Comment: Thanks; that at least generates a .deb, but it won't install: dpkg: error processing archive... trying to overwrite '/usr/share/aclocal/cmake.m4', which is also in package cmake-data 2.8.12.2-0ubuntu3

Comment: I tried using ccmake to set CPACK_BINARY_DEB to ON and rebuilding, and that produced a .deb file, but it has the same install problem.

Comment: Ubuntu makes two packages out of cmake by default, one with the binaries and one with the rest. You made one package with both. You can do apt remove cmake-data and your cmake install will proceed.