# How to create .deb package for tesseract?

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, cmake, tesseract, deb

I am trying to create a .deb installer for [specific version](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/releases/tag/4.0.0) of [tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract). This exact version is not shipped in ubuntu 20.04,
and I could not find it elsewhere and I need it for my project.

We can build and install it using cmake by following the steps given [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/INSTALL.GIT.md) which is working fine. The following are the commands I used to build and install tesseract from source using cmake:

```
sudo apt install -y git cmake gcc g++ pkg-config libleptonica-dev
git clone --branch 4.0.0 --depth 1 https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract
cd tesseract
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DBUILD_TRAINING_TOOLS=OFF
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

I tried with `sudo make checkinstall` but the target doesn't seem to exist. Can anyone with experience help me out in building a package installer instead of directly installing it from source.

The reason I want an installer is to integrate it easily with GitHub Actions using `ubuntu-latest` image. We can simply host the installer somewhere and let the github actions download the installer and install `tesseract` before each run.

Comment: CMake is shipped and intergrated with [cpack](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cpack.1.html) utility, which could be used for create a **package** from a CMake project. Have you tried to use it? E.g. `.deb` package could be created with `cpack -G DEB` command. See e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012811/how-to-build-a-deb-file-for-cmake-from-source) about creating a .deb package for CMake itself.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I attempted with `cpack -G DEB` it failed directly with `CPack Error: CPack project name not specified` so I added `include(CPack)` line in `CMakeLists.txt` but again another error happened, I am not sure this is the right path to go forward, maybe it is not configured with CPack...

Comment: While tesseract project has `install` directives, it actually doesn't enable CPack support. But you may add to the end of its `CMakeLists.txt` the line `include(CPack)` (and, probably, some other lines which sets CPack-related variables), so `cpack` will be able to generate `.deb` package for that project. I find adding such lines and using `cpack` to be a much easier way than preparing deb package from scratch. In any case, I don't understand what do you want from us. We won't create that `.deb` for you and send you resulted package. Nor we will search that package in the net.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tsyvarev pointed out, I probed into `cpack` and it worked well. `cmake` and `cpack` are new to me, and the following are the steps I followed to compile `4.0.0` version of tesseract on `ubuntu 20.04`:

### Clone the repo:

```
sudo apt install -y git cmake gcc g++ pkg-config libleptonica-dev
git clone --branch 4.0.0 --depth 1 https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract
```

### Edit CMakeLists.txt

Then we need to add the following lines at the end of `CMakeLists.txt` to enable cpack functionality and set required variables:

```
set(OSNAME "ubuntu_20.04")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE "amd64")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_MAINTAINER "<your name>")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_NAME "tesseract-ocr")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION "<description>")
# set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS "liblept5") # Manually adding the dependencies 
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_SHLIBDEPS ON) # This automatically determines required dependencies
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION ${PACKAGE_VERSION})
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME ${CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_NAME}_${PACKAGE_VERSION}_${CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE}_${OSNAME})
set(CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
set(CPACK_STRIP_FILES TRUE)
include(CPack)
```

I am using `OSNAME` variable to append it to generated filename. To find out `CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE` value, you can run `dpkg --print-architecture`, in my case it was `amd64`. You also need to give your name and description of the package as well.

### Creating the Debian package installer

```
cd tesseract
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DBUILD_TRAINING_TOOLS=OFF
make
cpack -G DEB
```

This will generate a debian package file: `tesseract-ocr_4.0.0_amd64_ubuntu_20.04.deb`

### Installing the package

Running `dpkg -i tesseract-ocr_4.0.0_amd64_ubuntu_20.04.deb` will give error that it needs `liblept5`

We can run the commands in the following order to install properly

```
sudo apt install liblept5
sudo dpkg -i tesseract-ocr_4.0.0_amd64_ubuntu_20.04.deb
sudo ldconfig
```

We can check whether tesseract is installed properly or not by running `tesseract --help`

### Uninstalling the package

The following will uninstall the package from the system

```
sudo dpkg -r tesseract-ocr
```

Comment: Probably a better approach would be to look into existing Debian packaging and backport it to the version you are trying to package.

Comment: Most probably this is the repo which has code for ubuntu packaging: https://github.com/AlexanderP/tesseract-debian, but I am not aware of how to go about making it work :(

Comment: Looks like you should be able to just unpack it on top and run `debuild` or what have you.